# Using javascript, how do I find the offsets of a selection from a parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, range

Suppose a user of my website selects some text in my web-page.  Suppose also that every element in the webpage has an id.
I want to save to a database the closest parent node to the text.
That part is easy, I just call:

```
firstnode = rangeThatUserHighlighted.commonAncestorContainer;
if (firstnode.nodeType == 3) {
        firstnode = firstnode.parentElement;
}
```

(Here the nodeType of 3 means the commonancestor is a text node, which means I have to get the parent of it.)
I can store the ID of that node in a database.  But  that is not enough information to recreate the selection on some other date.  (I have to be able to recreate the selection - not only on the original page, but also if the paragraph of html is moved to some other webpage in some other location relative to the BODY element.)
A range has offsets, so I thought I could do the following.

call:

```
rangeThatUserHighlighted.setStartBefore(firstnode);
```

then I could save "**rangeThatUserHighlighted.startOffset**" (and **endOffset**).

This gives me results that do not make sense.

I thought also of simply searching for the text to be highlighted, but that does not work for two reasons.  The same text might occur more than one time in my paragraph and I would not know which occurence to highlight.   Secondly, there might be formatting tags such as BOLD, ITALIC, etc that throw off the exact position.

So what is the answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a working sample, it will be easier to help

Comment: There are tons of answers about that on SO

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  First, the entire text and html being examined must be in one big DIV or ARTICLE tag.  Secondly, code must assign ids to each non-text tag: For example in jquery you might use the following few lines to create the tags:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var curid;
        var count = 0;
        // ArticletoHighlightRFS is the id of the article tag that encloses
        // the html paragraph(s)
        $("#ArticleToHighlightRFS").find("*").each(function (i) {

            curid = "" + this.id;
            if (curid.length < 1) {
                count = count + 1;
                this.id = "articlechild" + count;
            }
        });

    })
```

Now in the case where the user just highlights text, the anchor node and the text node will be the same - and it will be of type #text.  In that case, The key is to find the previous sibling to the #text node (which is easy, just call **'anchorNode.previousSibling'**.   You store the id of that node, and later, you can recreate the anchorNode by **document.getElementById(previousNodeID)** and then call .**nextSibling** on that, to get hold of the #text node again, which is your anchor node.  (this is a slight oversimplification but I supply the code, see next paragraph)

A working example is at jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/73nc02zs/3/).  To sum up, this code allows you to let a user highlight any paragraph or subset of a paragraph of html, and to save the information in a database, and later, if you output that paragraph in the same page in another page at another position to recreate the highlight.